# How do I process multipart http responses in Ruby Net:HTTP?

Tags: ruby, http, soap, multipart

There is so much information out there on how to generate multipart responses or do multipart file uploads. I can't seem to find any information on how to process a multipart http response. Here is some IRB output from a multipart http response I am working with.

```
>> response.http.content_type
=> "multipart/related"
>> response.http.body[0..2048]
=> "\r\n------=_Part_3_806633756.1271797659309\r\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\nContent-Id: <A0FCC4333C6D0FCA346B97FAB6B61818>\r\n\r\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns1:runReportResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:ns1="http://192.168.1.200:8080/jasperserver/services/repository"><ns2:result xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-rpc">runReportReturn</ns2:result><runReportReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;\n&lt;operationResult version=&quot;2.0.1&quot;&gt;\n\t&lt;returnCode&gt;&lt;![CDATA[0]]&gt;&lt;/returnCode&gt;\n&lt;/operationResult&gt;\n</runReportReturn></ns1:runReportResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>\r\n------=_Part_3_806633756.1271797659309\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\nContent-Id: <report>\r\n\r\n%PDF-1.4\n%\342\343\317\323\n3 0 obj
```

Comment: response.http.body[0..2048].split('\r\n') or maybe .split(/(?:\\r\\n){1,2}/) would put each part of the response into an array. You could put it into a hash with a bit of extra work, perhaps some of these snippets will help:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/302

It really all depends on what you actually want to do with the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rack to do that for you, here's the utility function that does it: [Rack::Utils::parse_multipart](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L512). Obviously you'll have to make your response object look like a request object Rack would accept (the env object).

Comment: You can use `httpadapter` to translate to something Rack understands.